# scaling workaround ? scaling issues

Tags: jquery, css, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/gubLwvkt/

```
#icon-wrap:hover {
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}
```

after the animation, the picture (even tried it before with a .svg) is in lower resolution

is there a way to work it around ?
what i like about these particular keyframes is that the div doesn't mess with the objects it's close to

the only workaround i found was abandoning keyframes and using a transition with size change (but that causes other problems though)

@edit
I've got to add that in Firefox it's just fine.
In Opera it's in lowquality for a few sec and it adjusts.
Internet Explorer is just fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome seems to view the backface when rendering the image since you got to use 3D transformation, you can fix this by setting the backface visibility to hidden for webkit :

```
#icon-wrap img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gubLwvkt/1/

Comment: You surely have to, hats-off for the lovely animation you have done :)

Comment: it's just a template from http://bouncejs.com/
Go check it out! The one i used is called jelly!